# Could this work? A partial solution to closed questions

Tags: discussion

I am just angry because right when I am in the middle of typing a bunch of stuff for a response, suddenly that "this question is closed" banner pops up and all that hard work goes down the drain. Perhaps someone who has Imperium around here will see this and consider: why can't we let any one already working on a post go ahead and post, kind of grandfather them in as it were, that only seems fair, then if you want to close then by all means. Would that work?

Comment: I agree that this is annoying but I think a change like this would have to be implemented by the corporation across all the SE sites. I don’t think users voting to close have any visibility into whether other users are working on answers, and I doubt that moderators do either. I’ve occasionally seen other users post a partial answer saying “answer still under construction”, or whatever, to get around this, but I don’t know whether that is considered OK behavior or not.

Comment: I think the intended approach is that you, the answerer, will then edit the question to make it acceptable. This assumes the question was unacceptable in the first place and that it's clear how to make it acceptable...

Comment: By the way, once you have 3000 reputation you'll have access to close votes, which doesn't just mean you can vote to close, but it also means you can see how many people have already voted to close (so you can decide not to start an answer). Not an excuse for the way things are, just a note that things will be less annoying for you eventually.

Comment: I started to write an answer to your question and realized it had lots of overlap with [my answer here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13431/44126), so I'll just link.

Comment: @rob That is excellent advice, on the order of: "why didn't I thik of that before going on meta and acting like an idiot"; thanks.

Comment: Re *"suddenly that "this question is closed" banner pops up and all that hard work goes down the drain"*: That is only [to fool you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95303/i-posted-an-answer-after-a-question-was-closed/95307#95307). You have a whopping 4 hours to finish it. Or at least had. It could have changed in the meantime. There is [a change list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: @PeterMortensen In general, using technical cleverness to override system restrictions is frowned upon.